# ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de insertar en SQLite grandes cantidades de registros ? Android Java

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqlite3

He revisado muchos ejemplos en distintas paginas y la gran mayoría enseñan a insertar 1 registro cada vez.  y esto lo hace correcto.

Pero para mi caso tengo una api que me devuelve una gran cantidad de datos, y el insertar 1 vez por cada registro  demora demasiado.

revisando el log indica que la memoria se esta limpiando, **ocasionando tiempos de espera muy grandes.**

**¿Cuál es la mejor manera de hacer estas inserciones de gran cantidades de datos.?**

Fracción del código

```
 public static String iterarDatos(SoapObject result, Context m_context) {
        String res = "";
        int nroRegistros = 0;
        ZEMTable zemTable = new ZEMTable(m_context);
        try {
            SoapObject szem = result;
            nroRegistros = szem.getPropertyCount();
            if (nroRegistros > 0) {

                 zemBE[] zems = WSManager.RetrievezemFromSoap(szem);
                zemTable.open();
                for (int i = 0; i < nroRegistros; i++) {
                    zemTable.create(zems[i]);
                }
                zemTable.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            
        }
        return res;
    }
```

donde el create es el siguiente.

```
 public long create(zemBE tzem){
  Log.i(TAG, "Inserting record...");
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
   
    initialValues.put(KEY_ID,zem.id);
    initialValues.put(KEY_REF,zem.ref);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DESCRIP,zem.descrip);
    initialValues.put(KEY_IDALMACEN,zem.idalmacen);

    
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
  }
```

Comment: Tu problema es que la app se congela hasta que todos los registros terminan de insertarse? Si es así, tienes que realizar la operación en otro hilo distinto del principal.

Comment: así es. se congela. pero en teoría debería esperar que termine.  solo que ese tiempo que se congela es mucho .

Comment: Puedes agregar el código?

Comment: si. dame un segundo.

Comment: Acabo de subir el código..   imaginar que son mas 32000 registros.. (ejemplo exagerado) .. el tiempo  va entre 40 minutos o 1 hora.. inclusive mas

Comment: Yo he utilizado `SQLiteStatement`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501516/android-sqlite-database-slow-insertion

Comment: me ayudas.. la función compileStatement no lo reconoce.

Comment: Creo que tienes que encontrar otra estrategia para tu app. Realmente necesitas todos esos datos guardados localmente? Van a utilizar bastante memoria en el dispositivo. Además que si los datos tardan varios minutos en bajar, no van a estar disponibles para su uso por todo ese tiempo.

Comment: Yo creo que una buena estrategia para guardar un registro de base de datos masivos podrías usar `Firebase` ya que sus servidores son lo suficiente preparados para este tipo de información.

Comment: utilice SQLiteStatement y me ayudo mucho. pero tiene un limite por caracteres.  alrededor de 396842 caracteres en la query.  intente hacer un bucle porque tengo mas registros pero me da error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue usar SQLiteStatement

me explico.

la siguiente query lo hace muy rápido.

insert tabla1 (campo1, campo2) value
('1','1'),('2','2'),('3','3'),('4','4'),('5','5'),('6','6'),('7','7'),('8','8'),('9','9')

de esta manera hace los insert consecutivos.